# ELF File Compiler Stamp

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, binary, elf

i found this Compiler Stamp in one ELF File: GCC: (Ubuntu 5.3.0-4ubuntu1~1.04.11) 5.4.0 20160622. Could someone tell me what information i can gather? For example the timestamp at the end. What does this mean?

Comment: In https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-5.4.0/ we see that gcc v 5.4.0 seems to have been built on June 3rd of 2016, which is a couple of weeks ***before*** the 22nd, so I am not sure what this means.

Comment: Yep. I didnt found any good explaination. This is why i asked

Comment: Well, 2016-06-03 is the tarball creation/upload date. The stamp date might well be the build date of the compiler this file was compiled with (the day ubuntu packagers took the tarball, configured and compiled GCC from it).

Answer (score 0):

> What does this mean?

It means that the compiler you used to build your program (or at least some object files that were linked into your program), is `GCC: (Ubuntu 5.3.0-4ubuntu1~1.04.11) 5.4.0`, and that that compiler itself was built on June 22, 2016.

There is nothing particularly important about this string or that date. It is simply a unique identifier of the compiler, which helps maintainers of your distribution.

Maintainers routinely have multiple versions of the compiler, and multiple applications built by these versions. When one such application crashes, the maintainer wants to quickly identify the compiler that built it, so the maintainer can investigate that crash further.